# Regular Expression - Matching part of a word, with one exception

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will look up "ship" in any instacne, so: ship, spaceships, starship, shipping etc. However it needs to not look up "warship". Also it needs to be case insensitive. At the moment I've got:

**(?!(warship))(?i)ship**

...which looks up "ship" but still looks up "warship" thanks to it containing "ship". I've tried:

**(?!(warship))^(?i)ship**

...which works to an extent but then "starship" doesn't get returned for example. I'm sure the answer is super-simple but I can't see it just now. Your help would be great!

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: does the starship,warship are present in separate lines?

Comment: The answer will be vastly different depending on what regex engine you're using, so please tell us which one it is.

Answer (score 2):

First I wanted to try negative lookbehind:

```
 /(?<!war)ship/
```

it should match all words instead of `warship`. But it gets the `ship` part only. So it is ok if you just check your string by regexp but doesn't work properly if you want to get the matched word.

Comment: OP wants to match the whole word not only ship.

Comment: Yes for case insensitive we have to add `i` modifier. `/(?<!war)ship/i`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for better solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?i)^(?!warship$)(?=.*ship).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vA4cI7/5)

It matches any instances of ship but not a `warship`

OR

```
(?i)\b\w*?(?<!war)ship\w*?\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vA4cI7/7)

Comment: Wow, brilliant! I had to add in case insensitivity so it's ended up as: ^(?!(?i)warship$)(?=.*(?i)ship).*  but this is now working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @M42 yep, op wants like that.

Comment: @user3725997 just `(?i)^(?!warship$)(?=.*ship).*` is enough.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, after my initial excitement, M42 was right, it only works if Warship is at the beginning of a string. I need to be able to match warship anywhere in the string. My fault for not clearly explaining that part.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the search string:

```
(?i)(\w*ships?)(?<!warship)(?<!warships)
```

`(?i)` ... enables case-insensitive search.

`(\w*ships?)` ... matches any string starting with 0 or more word characters, containing `ship` and optionally also plural `s` at end in a marking group. Also possible would be `(\b\w*ship\w*\b)` or `(\b[a-z]*ship[a-z]*\b)` to find only entire words containing anywhere `ship` inside.

`(?<!warship)(?<!warships)` ... two negative lookbehinds checking if the found word is whether `warship` nor `warships`.

Comment: This is the best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be using the .NET engine or something similarly expressive, so you can use lookbehind.

First you need a regex to match the entire word:

```
\w*ship\w*
```

Then you can easily modify it to not match anything where `war` comes before `ship`, using negative lookbehind.

```
\w*(?<!war)ship\w*
```

Also, there's probably no reason to specify the case insensitivity flag in the regex itself, just apply it to the regex object when you create it.